# Problem when printing text left and right of a dash with Split

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a "voyage" combobox that activates a second "departure_destination" combobox. In the second combobox I see the travel destinations separated by a dash, for example New York-Los Angeles, London-Liverpool, Paris-Montpellier

I would like to print the city to the left of the dash and the city to the right of the dash separately, then departure and destination. For example by selecting London-Liverpool, I would like to print `departure: London` and `destination: Liverpool`. I would like to print without creating a button

The problem is that when I try to print, it prints `Choose travel country` (and not the city to the left of the dash), while if I try to print the city to the right of the dash, I get the error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

I think the problem is here (because the comboboxes work correctly and get the records from the database correctly)

```
#PRINT
select_departure_destination = departure_destination.get()
    
if select_departure_destination:

    #City to the left of the dash
    departure = select_departure_destination.split('-')[0]
    print("departure", departure)
               
                
    #City to the right of the dash
    destination = select_departure_destination.split('-')[1]    
    print("destination", destination)
```

The complete executable code is:

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry('400x200')


conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
cursor = conn.cursor()   

#COMBOBOX
def combo_voyage():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT voyage FROM All_voyage') #for example United States, Great Britain, France
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def combo_departure_destination(event=None):
    val = voyage.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT departure_city||"-"||destination_city FROM departure_destination WHERE voyage = ?', (val,)) #for example New York-Los Angeles, London-Liverpool, Paris-Montpellier
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor] 
    departure_destination['value'] = values
    return values

voyage=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
voyage['value'] = combo_voyage()
voyage.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_departure_destination)
voyage.place(x=42, y=8)
voyage.set("Choose travel country")

departure_destination=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
#REMOVE departure_destination['value'] = combo_partita()
departure_destination.place(x=42, y=48)
departure_destination.set("Choose departure-destination")


#PRINT
select_departure_destination = departure_destination.get()
    
if select_departure_destination:

    #City to the left of the dash
    departure = select_departure_destination.split('-')[0]
    print("departure", departure)
                          
    #City to the right of the dash
    destination = select_departure_destination.split('-')[1]    
    print("destination", destination)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't do the split twice.  Use `departure, destination = select_departure_destination.split('-')`.

Comment: Is the stuff in the "#PRINT" section actually part of a function?  Remember that NOTHING will even get drawn until you get to `root.mainloop`.  Until then, it's all a bunch of messages waiting to be processed.  You can't read the combobox until you get a callback that a button was clicked or the combobox was changed.

Comment: @TimRoberts But if I don't do the division twice, I can't specify that I need [0] and [1]. Things in PRINT are not part of any function. I don't want to use buttons. So what would the solution be? Thank you

Comment: The code I gave you above will do the EXACT thing you want, without doing the operation twice.  `split` returns a list of 2 things, which we assign to 2 items.

Comment: You need to bind a function to the `departure_destionation` `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event, exactly like you do for `voyage`.  That fuinction is where you can do the code you have under "#PRINT", because only then do you know that something has been selected.

Comment: @TimRoberts Your code speeds up a job, but it's not the solution, because the result is always the same as the question problem. When I select, for example London-Liverpool, I don't print departure: London and destination: Liverpool. So the solution is to create a function? Without function, can't I solve the problem?

Comment: In order to READ the user's departure/destination choice, you have to be told that the user has MADE such a choice.  The way you get told is to bind a function to the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event, exactly as you have done with `voyage`.  It's the same process.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok. Do I need to create a function?

Comment: @TimRoberts Is the creation of the function obligatory?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have difficulty. Could you show me an answer with the code please? Thank you

Comment: You already have a combo box handler in `combo_departure_destination`.  You bind your new function the exact same way (with a different name, of course), and the code is basically what you have under "#PRINT".

Comment: @TimRoberts I created departure_destination.bind ('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_departure_destination), but it still doesn't print anything

Comment: No, because that function is already serving a different purpose.  You need to create a NEW function that gets the combobox value and prints the result.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you show me how please? You are kind, but these comments are confusing me. Of course I will vote on your answer and accept it as a solution if you help me solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little disturbed that you couldn't build this function based on what you already had.  Notice that I have renamed your `combo_departure_destination` to `combo_voyage`, since it is handling the `voyage` box, and have moved your "#PRINT" code into `combo_departure_destination`.

I'm also not sure why you are printing the result, since the application is a GUI function.  You would usually store the answer in a text box in the GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
root.geometry('400x200')

conn = sqlite3.connect('cities.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()   

def fill_voyage():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT voyage FROM All_voyage')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def combo_voyage(event=None):
    val = voyage.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT departure_city||"-"||destination_city FROM departure_destination WHERE voyage = ?', (val,)) 
    values = [row[0] for row in cursor] 
    print(values)
    departure_destination['value'] = values
    return values

def combo_departure_destination(event=None):
    select_departure_destination = departure_destination.get()
    if select_departure_destination:
        departure,destination = select_departure_destination.split('-')
        print("departure", departure)
        print("destination", destination)

voyage=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
voyage['value'] = fill_voyage()
voyage.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_voyage)
voyage.place(x=42, y=8)
voyage.set("Choose travel country")

departure_destination=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25)
departure_destination.place(x=42, y=48)
departure_destination.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_departure_destination)
departure_destination.set("Choose departure-destination")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The reason I'm printing the result is just for a little test. Actually I need departure and destination because I have to use them in other ways in the GUI. So I just needed to get the departure and destination. IMPORTANT QUESTION: Now, can I safely use departure and destination for other purposes? Can I call them elsewhere / outside in this window or can't they be called outside the combo_departure_destination function?

Comment: Yes, as I feared unfortunately. If I try to use departure or destination for other things in the window, I get the error NameError: name 'departure' is not defined. I needed to use this outside of the function. In fact, in my code, I created and defined departure and destination so that I could use them anywhere in the window. With your code, I can't. For example if I write to give you an example: if departure == London: print ("Ok, good"), I get the error NameError: name 'departure' is not defined. How can you fix this "problem" with your code?

Comment: I voted for your answer, even though it didn't help. I hope you can help me. You've been kind. I'm waiting for your answer. Thank you

Comment: You need to understand Python if you're going to write in Python.  If you put those two  statements inside the `combo_departure_destination` function where those names are used, then it would work just fine, as evidenced by the `print` statements that are already in there.  Remember, until that function runs, nothing has been selected.  Where were you trying to do your `if` / `print("Ok, good")`?